# Adjust the individual position of the labels on the chart

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to adjust the label position, but that seems to be fixed. What's wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{weatherdata.dat}
month;insulation 1931-1960;anchor 1;insulation 1981-2010;anchor 2
January;192.2;south;185.8;north
February;173.0;north;186.6;south
March;195.9;south;192.5;north
April;183.2;north;168.7;north
May;197.9;south;179.0;south
June;201.5;west;170.6;north
July;219.9;{south east};184.4;{south east}
August;219.3;west;184.4;{north east}
September;156.8;east;140.8;east
October;152.2;south;144.8;{north west}
November;153.2;south;150.3;{north east}
December;153.5;north;158.2;south
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header = true]
{weatherdata.dat}\wheatertable


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 15cm,
        height = 7cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        smooth,
        line width = 1 pt, 
        ymajorgrids = true,
        yminorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Total insulation [h]},
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        nodes near coords = {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        xticklabels from table = {\wheatertable}{month},
        every node near coord/.append style={%
            rotate=0,
            font=\scriptsize,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},
            /pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}        
            },%label above bar
        enlarge x limits=0.05,
        ymin=135,
        ymax=230,
        ylabel style={rotate=0},
        x tick label style={font=\small,align=right, rotate = 45, anchor = east},%text width=3.0cm},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={%
            at={(0.98,1.1)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex,
            font = \scriptsize
        }%%
        ]
        \addplot[style={blue, mark=*},
            x = \coordindex,
            y = \thisrowno{1},
            visualization depends on = {\thisrowno{2} \as \firstanchor},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\firstanchor},
            ] 
        table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 1] {\wheatertable};
        \addlegendentry{1931-1960};
        \addplot[style={red,mark=square*},
            visualization depends on = {\thisrowno{4} \as \secondanchor},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\secondanchor},     
            ] 
        table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 3] {\wheatertable};
        \addlegendentry{1981-2010};
    %   \addplot[top color=red!20, bottom color=cyan!20] fill between[of=min and max];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this before and am not claiming that the following is the best solution. For some reason the anchor gets overwritten by the y coordinate, i.e. the meta value. Here is one possible way to fix this: instead of `visualization depends on` use the `scatter/@pre marker code` to get the anchors. (Recall that `nodes near coords` is a scatter plot of nodes.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{weatherdata.dat}
month;insulation 1931-1960;anchor 1;insulation 1981-2010;anchor 2
January;192.2;south;185.8;north
February;173.0;north;186.6;south
March;195.9;south;192.5;north
April;183.2;north;168.7;north
May;197.9;south;179.0;south
June;201.5;west;170.6;north
July;219.9;{south east};184.4;{south east}
August;219.3;west;184.4;{north east}
September;156.8;east;140.8;east
October;152.2;south;144.8;{north west}
November;153.2;south;150.3;{north east}
December;153.5;north;158.2;south
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header = true]
{weatherdata.dat}\wheatertable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 15cm,
        height = 7cm,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        smooth,
        line width = 1 pt, 
        ymajorgrids = true,
        yminorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Total insulation [h]},
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        nodes near coords= {\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{[index]2}\of\wheatertable%#1=row, #2=column
        \edef\firstanchor{\pgfplotsretval}% 
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{[index]4}\of\wheatertable%#1=row, #2=column
        \edef\secondanchor{\pgfplotsretval}%    
        },
        xtick = data,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        xticklabels from table = {\wheatertable}{month},
        every node near coord/.append style={%
            rotate=0,
            font=\scriptsize,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},
            /pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}        
            },%label above bar
        enlarge x limits=0.05,
        ymin=135,
        ymax=230,
        ylabel style={rotate=0},
        x tick label style={font=\small,align=right, rotate = 45, anchor = east},%text width=3.0cm},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={%
            at={(0.98,1.1)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex,
            font = \scriptsize
        }%%
        ]
        \addplot[style={blue, mark=*},
            x = \coordindex,
            y = \thisrowno{1},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor/.expanded=\firstanchor},
            ] 
        table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 1] {\wheatertable};
        \addlegendentry{1931-1960};
        \addplot[style={red,mark=square*},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\secondanchor},     
            ] 
        table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 3] {\wheatertable};
        \addlegendentry{1981-2010};
    %   \addplot[top color=red!20, bottom color=cyan!20] fill between[of=min and max];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]